# Cumulants of discrete uniform distribution from Bernoulli numbers

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, bernoulli-numbers, cumulants

Let $X$ be the random variable uniformly distributed on $\{0,\dots,d-1\}$. This is,
$$\operatorname{Prob}(X = i) = \frac{1}{d}$$
for $i \in \{0,\dots,d-1\}$. Computations suggest that the cumulants of $X$ are, for $n \geq 2$, given by
$$\kappa_n(X) = \frac{B_n}{n} (d^n-1)$$
where $B_n$ is the $n$-th Bernoulli number.

> Where can I find this stated in the presented form?

The moments are given by
$$m_n(X) = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} k^n = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j B_j \binom{n}{j}\frac{(d-1)^{n-j+1}}{n-j+1}.$$

> How can the above formula be derived from this?